# Problems with special characters in php imagestring

Tags: php, string, image, character-encoding, jpeg

everybody.

my code is

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
        $imgPath = 'logo.jpg'; 
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgPath);
        $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 000, 000, 255);
        $string = "A&B UK LIMITED";
        $fontSize = 5;
        $x = 19;
        $y = 197;
        imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x, $y, $string, $color);
        imagejpeg($image,"test.jpg", 85);
?>
```

in code $string variable has a special character and that why my code doesn't work
is there any body know how to fix this problem,

but If i cahange the value of $string variable it does work. Example $string="test Company";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like below

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$imgPath = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/37/VII-200-bakside.jpg'; 
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgPath);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0,0, 250);
$string = "A&B UK LIMITED";
$fontSize = 5;
$x = 50;
$y = 50;
imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x, $y, $string, $color);
imagejpeg($image,'test.jpeg',75);
imagejpeg($image);
```

output:

[image: output image]